# 404 error when upgrading from Tomcat7 / Jersey 2.25 / Servlet 2.5 to Tomcat 10 / Jersey 3.0.8 / Servlet 5

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I have a Jersey application running on Tomcat that we've had up for several years.
We are currently upgrading to Java 11 and Tomcat 10, which necessitates Servlet 5.0 and Jersey 3.0.8

After satisfying all of the compile needs, and any runtime errors of "class not found", I am running into a problem I have been bashing my head against all day.  No matter what I try, I keep getting a 404 error.

I tried changing the original application from ResourceConfig:

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public AppConfig() {
        packages("com.carpart.webservices.rest.oauth");
        property(JspMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "/");
        register(JspMvcFeature.class);
    }
}
```

to a subclass of application, overriding getClasses:

```
    public class AppConfig extends Application {
        
        @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
            Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
            s.add( Connect.class );
            return s;
        }
        
    }
```

I've tried different web.xml variations from the original filter to the wording on the Jersey documentation:

Original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<filter>
    <filter-name>Jersey</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.carpart.webservices.rest.oauth.AppConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <filter-name>Jersey</filter-name>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

New:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="5.0"
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.carpart.webservices.rest.oauth.AppConfig</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
     
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.carpart.webservices.rest.oauth.AppConfig</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 
 </web-app>
```

I've tried setting an @ApplicationPath on the application to various values from "/" to "/*" to "/api" just to see if I could get some different reaction.

The Connect class is defined as such:

```
@Path("/connect")
public class Connect {

    @GET
    @Path("/authorize")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response authorize(@QueryParam("client_id") String client_app_id ) {
        log.debug("Inside authorize (phase 1) GET method...");
    }
}
```

The Connect resource class hasn't changed. from what we had.

I've read the Jersey 3.0.8 documentation several times with regards to configuring and deploying, but I am not seeing what is wrong.

Comment: Note, we are stuck using Tomcat 10, OpenJDK 11, and Jersey.  We build with Apache Ant, so no poms or the like. I can send the entire classpath and list of jars that get put into the war file if need be.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.carpart.webservices.rest.oauth.AppConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
```

If you're using Jersey 3, then `javax` needs to be changed to `jakarta`. No more Javax anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I found the issue! (Thank you Paul, your comment below the code helped trigger my thoughts this morning!)

I was still including the javax.* pathed classes in my Connect class for the annotations. I deleted them and re imported them all as jakarta.ws.rs.* and it recognized the Connect class as a resource.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).